# awk syntax error inside script while assigning it to a variable

Tags: awk

Basically memory is a variable. In a script, I am trying to remote login to one server and execute free command to check memory usage and using awk I'm getting the usage in percentage. But I am getting syntax error for the below.

```
memory=`ssh $line -n "free | grep Mem | awk '{ print $3/$2 *100.0 }'"`

echo -e "The memory usage is: $memory" >>$LOGFILE
```

Error is:

```
awk: { print / *100.0 }
awk:          ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: { print / *100.0 }
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that `$3` and `$2` are substituted by the shell (with nothing when unassigned) before the command runs, because they are enclosed in double quotes.

The single quotes inside the double quotes don't prevent that:

```
$ echo "'$unassigned'"
''
```

You should escape the `$`:

```
memory=$(ssh $line -n "free | awk '/Mem/ { print \$3/\$2 *100.0 }'")
```

---

Alternatively, you could run only `free` on the server, and `awk` on the client.

```
memory=$(ssh $line -n "free" | awk '/Mem/ { print $3/$2 *100.0 }')
```